# Convert Left outer join query into Entity Framework query

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a sql statement that I want to be able to convert into EF4.

Its a simple Left outer join that looks like

```
SELECT * 
FROM EntryDate 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Member on Member.CardId = EntryDate.CardID
```

how do I do this using the entity framework 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is relation mapped in your model you can simply use navigation properties because they always use left join:

```
var data = members.EntryDates;
```

I expect you don't have such relation because `CardId` doesn't look like primary key of `Member` or `EntryDate`.

If you don't have navigation properties you must use

```
var query = from m in context.Members
            join e in context.EntryDates on m.CardId equals e.CardId into x
            from res in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
               Member = m,
               EntryDate = res
            };
```

This works only in EFv4+ because EFv1 didn't support `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav, yes I dont have any navigation properties so I had to use the 2nd option